# Why are $2$-covectors on $\mathbb{R}^3$ decomposable?

Tags: exterior-algebra

How do you show that every $2$-covector $\omega\in\Lambda^2((\mathbb{R}^3)^\ast)$ is decomposable i.e. that
$$\omega=u\wedge v$$
for some $u,v\in(\mathbb{R}^3)^\ast$?

In general we have
$$\omega=\omega_{12}e^1\wedge e^2+\omega_{13}e^1\wedge e^3+\omega_{23}e^2\wedge e^3,$$
so we can set
$$\omega_{12}e^1\wedge e^2+\omega_{13}e^1\wedge e^3+\omega_{23}e^2\wedge e^3=(a_1e^1+a_2e^2+a_3e^3)\wedge(b_1e^1+b_2e^2+b_3e^3),$$
and try to solve for $a_i,b_i$. But there doesn't seem to have a well-defined solution to these equations unless we separate it in several different cases ($\omega_{12} \neq 0$, etc). What's a better way of proving it?

Comment: FWIW, this follows from the occasionally useful fact that a $2$-covector $\omega$ (on any f.d. vector space) is decomposable iff $\omega \wedge \omega = 0$, but presumably you don't have access to it here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do this without the case splitting you mention, but it uses the important *Hodge star* operator, which, given the question, you may or may not have available:

Pick an inner product $\langle \, , \, \rangle$ and orientation on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the usual ones will do), which defines a volume form $\Omega \in \Lambda^3 (\mathbb{R}^3)^*$; this defines a Hodge star operator $$\ast: \Lambda^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)^* \to (\mathbb{R}^3)^*$$ characterized by
$$\alpha \wedge \ast \beta = \langle \alpha, \beta \rangle \Omega,$$
where $\langle \, , \, \rangle$ here denotes the induced inner product on $\Lambda^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)^*$.

Henceforth assume that $\omega \neq 0$ (if $\omega = 0$ it is clearly decomposable, as in that case $\omega = 0 \wedge 0$). Now, $\ast \omega$ is a $1$-form, and we can extend it to some orthogonal basis $(\ast \omega, \zeta, \eta)$ of $(\mathbb{R}^3)^*$. Then, $(\omega, \ast \zeta, \ast \eta)$ is an orthogonal basis of $\Lambda^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)^*$. Computing gives that
\begin{align}
    \langle \zeta \wedge \eta, \ast \zeta \rangle \Omega &= \zeta \wedge \eta \wedge \zeta = 0 \\
    \langle \zeta \wedge \eta, \ast \eta \rangle \Omega &= \zeta \wedge \eta \wedge \eta = 0 ,\\
\end{align}
so by orthogonality $\omega$ is a multiple of $\zeta \wedge \eta$, and in particular $\omega$ is decomposable.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the components of the wedge product with respect to a basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ and the induced basis $(e_2 \wedge e_3, e_3 \wedge e_1, e_1 \wedge e_2)$ are given by the familiar cross product. More precisely,
$$\omega_{23}e^2\wedge e^3 + \omega_{31}e^3\wedge e^1 + \omega_{12}e^1\wedge e^2= (a_1e^1+a_2e^2+a_3e^3)\wedge(b_1e^1+b_2e^2+b_3e^3)$$
is equivalent to $$(\omega_{23}, \omega_{31}, \omega_{12}) = (a_1, a_2, a_3) \times (b_1, b_2, b_3).$$ So, the statement that every $2$-covector $\omega \in \Lambda^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)^*$ is decomposable is equivalent to the statement that every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as the cross product of two other vectors.

But this latter claim is easy to prove: Pick any two linearly independent vectors $X, Y$ orthogonal to $\ast \omega := (\omega_{23}, \omega_{31}, \omega_{12})$. Then, by construction $X \times Y$ is some multiple of $\ast \omega$, and by rescaling, say, $X$, we can ensure that $\ast \omega = X \times Y$. (In fact, the relationship between $\wedge$ and $\times$ can be written in terms of the Hodge star operator and the isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^3 \cong (\mathbb{R}^3)^*$ determined by the standard inner product.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using clifford algebra.  Call a product of $k$ vectors under the clifford product a $k$-versor.  Versors are closed under multiplication: the product of two versors is another versor.  Note that a $k$-vector that is also a versor is necessarily simple.

Now, consider a bivector $B$ that might not be simple.  Multiply it by $\epsilon = e_1 e_2 e_3$, the unit pseudoscalar, which is also a versor (this is the operation of Hodge duality Travis mentions).  The result is necessarily some vector.  All vectors are simple, and all vectors are versors.  $B\epsilon$ is some vector.

Now, consider $(B \epsilon) \epsilon^{-1}$. The result is necessarily a bivector, but it also must be a versor since $B\epsilon$ is a vector.  But $B \epsilon \epsilon^{-1} = B$, and since the product operation is associative, this implies $B$ is a versor, and therefore a simple $2$-vector.